# Restrict adding multiple blank rows in tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using tabulator in Angular.I wanted to add new blank row on a button click,
so I am adding a new row by using  `this.table.addRow({});`
But every time I click on button, its adding blank row. But I don't want multiple blank rows to be added in Table.
Can I prohibit adding blank row if already one blank row is added?
How I can find out number of blank rows in table ?

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator itself has no concept of a "blank row" all, rows are just objects and the table will visualize the data contained in those objects.

But you could use the `searchRows` function with a custom filter to retrieve the empty rows and check this before triggering the `addRow` function:

```js
var emptyRowCount = table.searchRows((data) => { return Object.keys(data).length }).length
```